# Set a specific date for a GIT tag

Tags: git

I want to retroactively add an annotated tag to an old project at some commit back in time.

Rather than have annotated tag show today's date, is it possible to set (or edit) the date of a tag?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$ GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2006-10-02 10:31" git tag -s v1.0.1
```

References:

- https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html#_on_backdating_tags